# Spark Java Dataset classifying rows by range

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on spark Java project and I have to classify entry of an dataset.

So, I have input dataset :
df1

```
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+
    |           id|     capability     |  time       |
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+
    |      5000447|C20                 |24           |
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+
    |      4500456|C40                 |3            |
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

df2

```
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+
    |       minval|     maxval         |  range      |
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+
    |      0      |3                   |]0,3]        |
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+
    |      3      |25                  |]3,25]       |
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

I would like to have in output :

```
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+
    |           id|     capability     |  time       |  range      |
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+
    |      1800447|C20                 |24           |]3,25]       |
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+
    |      1800456|C40                 |3            |]0,3]        |
    +-------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

How can I do that ?
Thanks for your help.
I am working in spark Java .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `join` can do the trick if you specify the checks between the ranges for every `time` row value, while dropping the columns you don't need afterwards (inner join is the default type of join in Spark as seen [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html)):

```
// Java and Scala
df1.join(df2, (df1("time") > df2("minval")).and(df1("time") <= df2("maxval")))
          .drop("minval", "maxval")
          .show()

// Scala only
df1.join(df2, df1("time") > df2("minval") && df1("time") <= df2("maxval"))
          .drop("minval", "maxval")
          .show()
```

This is the output by using the `show` action method:

```
+-------+----------+----+------+
|     id|capability|time| range|
+-------+----------+----+------+
|5000447|       C20|  24|]3,25]|
|4500456|       C40|   3| ]0,3]|
+-------+----------+----+------+
```